# Inserting drivers into BartPE ISO image?

Tags: drivers, iso

Is it possible to insert drivers (sata) directly into an BartPE image, or would I have to build it from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press F6 during boot and load them from a floppy, but you'll need to rebuild the image if you want them to be part of the normal boot process.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely rebuild the image. I've found that any driver I need once I'm likely to need again. Drivers for things like SATA should be very handy to have ready all the time.